# Clojure protocols - dispatch only on 2-arity version of multi-arity function

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, arity

**Short Version**

I want a multi-arity function to dispatch on type for the 2-arity version, but I want the 1-arity version identical across all types.

**Long Version (With Example)**

I have a protocol that looks something like this

```
(defprotocol foo
  (bar [d] [d x]))
```

If I want "TypeA" to extend this protocol, then I have the following

```
(extend-protocol foo
  TypeA
  (bar
    ([d] #(bar d %))
    ([d x] (TypeA-fn x))))
```

for some function TypeA-fn specific to TypeA.

If I want "TypeB" to extend this protocol then I have the following

```
(extend-protocol foo
  TypeB
  (bar
    ([d] #(bar d %))
    ([d x] (TypeB-fn x))))
```

for some function TypeB-fn specific to TypeB.

The effect that I am trying to create is that of currying.

```
(bar instance-of-TypeA x)
```

is a double, say, whilst

```
(bar instance-of-TypeA)
```

returns a function that maps TypeA to a double.

The point is that the single arity implementation of bar is always the same, whilst the multiple arity implementation depends on the type. Naturally I don't want to repeat myself every time I extend this protocol for the single-arity version, so what is the idiomatic clojure way to do this. I have considered not specifying a single arity version, and using (partial bar TypeX) everywhere, but I grow tired of partial.

**proposed solution**
I could wrap the original function inside a new function, for example

```
(defprotocol foo
  (bar-method [d x]))

(extend-protocol foo
  TypeA
  (bar-method
    ([d x] (TypeA-fn x))))

(defn bar
([d] (fn [x] (bar-method d x))
([d x] (bar-method d x))
```

but the introduction of two functions for the purpose of one seems inelegant.

Comment: Have you considered multimethods? Also, sometimes nothing beats a good old `(cond ...)` expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution is exactly what I would suggest. You want a function of one or two arguments; in the two-argument case you want it to be polymorphic, so it makes sense for that case to forward to something that does polymorphic dispatch.